# Integrate $\int_{0}^{n}{[2^x]}$, where $n$ is a natural number

Tags: integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Source: MAT $2014$. Integrate the following -
$$\int_{0}^{n}{[2^x]}$$
I thought of reversing $\frac{d}{dx}(a^x) = a^xln(a)$. So I divide and multiply by $ln(2)$. I end up with the final answer being
$$\frac{2^n-1}{ln(2)}$$
This is not an answer in the multiple choices. I believe it's the floor function not allowing me to use the differentiation of $a^x$. How should I go about integrating a floor function?

Comment: What does $[-]$ denote here?

Comment: Hint. The integrand is constant between integers, so the integral is a sum of rectangles. Write the integral as that sum. You can't do this problem routinely with the fundamental theorem of calculus. You actually have to think about what it means.

Comment: @AnneBauval my bad, missed that part